# HTML сайт на node.js

Tags: html, сервер, windows-xp

Создал сайт полностью на HTML, хочу в локалку вывести,а node.js не качает.

Пишет "only Windows 7", у меня windows xp.

Есть ли еще возможности вывести в локалку?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Моё портфолио</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="cacaca">
    <h1 align="center">Мой сайт портфолио</h1>
    <form action="auth.php" method="post">
      <input type="Text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Введите Login">
      <input type="Password" name="pswrd" id="pswrd" title="Password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
      <input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Войти">
      <input type="reset" value="Сброс">
    </form>
    <hr color="#000000">
    <div>
       <h2 class="section-title">Мои контакты</h2>
        <div>
         <h3 style="color: blue">Я в соц.сетях</h3>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="http://vk.com/shnurov1954" target="_blank" title="Вконтакте" style="color: blue">VK</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004817147766" target="_blank" style="color: red" title="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h2 class="section-title">Обо мне</h2>
     <div>
      <img src="1.jpg" alt="ERROR" title="Юлий Высоцкий" width="250" height="300" border="1" id="Ava">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3 align="justify" class="section-title">Моя биография</h3>
     <p><b>
    Дон Вито Корлеоне (Андолини)</b> (7 декабря 1891— 29 июля 1955) (итал. Vito Andolini (Corleone), урожд. <b>Карлеоне</b> — сицилийский город в провинции Палермо) по прозвищу <b>«Крёстный отец»</b> — главный герой романа Марио Пьюзо «Крёстный отец» и основанного на нём фильма Фрэнсиса Форда Копполы.<div> Фамилию Карлеоне Вито получил при въезде в США, когда регистратор ошибочно вписал в графу "Фамилия" место рождения Дона. Он возглавлял один из самых могущественных кланов итало-американской мафии — семейство Корлеоне.</div>
     </p>
        <p>
    Проснувшись однажды утром после беспокойного сна, Грегор Замза обнаружил, что он у себя в постели превратился в страшное насекомое. Лежа на панцирнотвердой спине, он видел, стоило ему приподнять голову, свой коричневый, выпуклый, разделенный дугообразными чешуйками живот, на верхушке которого еле держалось готовое вот-вот окончательно сползти одеяло. Его многочисленные, убого тонкие по сравнению с остальным телом ножки беспомощно копошились у него перед глазами. «Что со мной случилось?» – подумал он. Это не было сном. Его комната, настоящая, разве что слишком маленькая, но обычная комната, мирно покоилась в своих четырех хорошо знакомых стенах. Над столом, где были разложены распакованные образцы сукон – Замза был коммивояжером, – висел портрет, который он недавно вырезал из иллюстрированного журнала и вставил в красивую золоченую рамку. На портрете была изображена дама в меховой шляпе и боа, она сидела очень прямо и протягивала зрителю тяжелую меховую муфту, в которой целиком исчезала ее рука. Затем взгляд Грегора устремился в окно, и пасмурная погода – слышно было, как по жести подоконника стучат капли дождя – привела его и вовсе в грустное настроение. «Хорошо бы еще немного поспать и забыть всю эту чепуху», – подумал он, но это было совершенно неосуществимо, он привык спать на правом боку, а в теперешнем своем </div></p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <h2 align="center" class="section-title">Моя статистика</h2>
       <table align="center" width="40%" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
        <tr align="center">
         <th bgcolor="#ffffff">Вид проекта</th>
         <th>Сделано</th>
         <th bgcolor="#ff0000">Выкуплено</th>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
         <td bgcolor="cacaca">Статичный</td>
         <td data-max="100">86</td>
         <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
         <td bgcolor="cacaca">Адаптивный</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>20</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам не обязательно использовать Node.js. Вы можете поставить любой веб-сервер. Например:

- [IIS](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/iiiisin2.mspx?mfr=true)
- [Tiny Server](http://tinyserver.sourceforge.net/)
- [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html)
- [XAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.2/)